# python manage.py runserver _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

Tags: mysql, django

Im trying to run "python manage.py runserver", I already installed mysql, django and the appropriate tools to use them together: Mysql-django. When trying to run I got this error:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x110251450>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 411, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: **(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")**
```

This is the content of my settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'django',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your MySQL server running?

Comment: Is your MySQL server configured to listen on `/tmp/mysql.sock`?

Comment: @Sarnold Nope, how can I configured it?

Comment: The socket to use will be in the [MySQL configuration file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_socket).

Comment: With the settings.py database HOST configured for either `''` or `'localhost'`, killing the mysql process and then trying to start the dev server produces an error like that where it looks for "/tmp/mysql.sock". This would mean what sarnold suggests, that your mysql is specifically running on a different unix socket

Comment: @Sarnold I opened /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config and founded this 
`version='5.5.25'
socket='/tmp/mysql.sock'
ldflags=''`  Is this the correct socket?

Comment: Excellent; that either means that your mysqld isn't running, couldn't open the socket, or refused the connection. What's `perror 2` output on your system?

Comment: @Sarnold I`m sorry exactly how can I output the perror 2? I tried running  `mysql -u root -p` in the console and it worked, I´m able to see my databases etc

Comment: Just type `perror 2` at your shell..

Comment: The problem was that I was using python3, and django is currently no no compatible.

Comment: @user1467736 is this related to the version of Python really? I have this problem but I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem also. You can solve this problem simply by changing the DB host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I literally wasted 2 hours trying to find the problem. Thank god I saw this!

Answer (score 1):

To find where is your mysql socket, in order to config it type

```
mysql_config --socket
```

get the result and apply it:

```
'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Even though I'm using MAMP, but this should work in other scenarios