# OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql.sock

when connecting to mysql database in Django ,I get the error.

1. I'm sure mysql server is running.
2. /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock doesn't exist.
3. When I run `$ find / -name *.sock -type s`, I only get /tmp/mysql.sock and some other irrelevant output.
4. I added `socket = /tmp/mysql.sock` to /etc/my.cnf. And then restared mysql, exited django shell, and connected to mysql database. I still got the same error.

I searched a lot, but I still don't know how to do.

Any help is greate. Thanks in advance.

Well, I just tried some ways. And it works.
I did as follows.

1. Add `socket = /tmp/mysql.sock` .Restart the mysql server.
2. `ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

I met an another problem today. I can't login to mysql.
I'm newbie to mysql. So I guess mysql server and client use the same socket to communicate.
I add `socket = /var/mysqld/mysqld.sock` to [mysqld] [client] block in my.cnf  and it wokrs.

Comment: Could you connect locally to your MySQL server using [MySQL CLI](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)? (Something like that: `mysql -u you_user_name -p`)

Comment: What is your `DATABASES` settings?

Comment: I can connect to mysql server using mysql -u user_name -p . I set database as django recomended

Comment: Could you set `socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` directly? That way you don't have to link `/tmp/mysql.sock` to that path manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use "127.0.0.1", instead of "localhost"

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': 'django',
      'USER': 'root',
      'PASSWORD': '',
      'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
      'PORT': '3306',
   }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why that would make any difference? Isn't localhost the same as 127.0.0.1 in most cases?

Comment: This is one of those bittersweet moments we all have in software development sometime: I'm glad it worked, but at the same time I have no idea WHY it did work. Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked
add OPTIONS attribute with read_default_file and give it the path of my.cnf file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf',
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your HOST from `'localhost'` to `'127.0.0.1'` and check your django app :)

Answer (score 0):

in flask, you may use that

`app=Flask(__name__)`

`app.config["MYSQL_HOST"]="127.0.0.1` 
`app.config["MYSQL_USER"]="root"`...

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when connecting MySQL with Django when using **Docker**.

Try `'PORT':'0.0.0.0'`.

Do not use `'PORT': 'db'`. This will not work if you tried to run your app outside Docker.