# Install mysql in dockerfile?

Tags: python, mysql, docker, mariadb, dockerfile

I want to write simple python application and put in docker conteiner with dockerfile. My dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:saucy

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install python
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install mysql-server python-mysqldb

# Add our python app code to the image
RUN mkdir -p /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Set the default command to execute
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

In my python application I only want to connect to the database. main.py look something like this:

```
import MySQLdb as db

connection = db.connect(
                host='localhost',
                port=3306,
                user='root',
                passwd='password',
            )
```

When I built docker image with:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

and run docker image with:

```
docker run -i myapp
```

I got error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Err, the database isn't running? It would be easier and make more sense to put the DB in a separate container.

Comment: I do not understand. How to run database. If I install mysql on my host computer, and try to connect to database on my host it working as it should to work. Is that mean that database on my host is running?

Comment: You should've just search for your error message: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11657829/484666), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11990708/484666), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11443504/484666) - it is not related to Docker or the way you use it.

Comment: It's just that the db isn't started by default in Docker like it is in Ubuntu normally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you've never started the database - you need to explicitly start services in most Docker images. But if you want to run two processes in Docker (the DB and your python program), things get a little more complex. You either have to use a process manager like supervisor, or be a bit cleverer in your start-up script.

To see what I mean, create the following script, and call it `cmd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqld &
python main.py
```

Add it to the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:saucy

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install python
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install mysql-server python-mysqldb

# Add our python app code to the image
RUN mkdir -p /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Set the default command to execute
COPY cmd.sh /cmd.sh
RUN chmod +x /cmd.sh
CMD cmd.sh
```

Now build and try again. (Apologies if this doesn't work, it's off the top of my head and I haven't tested it).

Note that this is *not* a good solution; mysql will not be getting signals proxied to it, so probably won't shutdown properly when the container stops. You could fix this by using a process manager like supervisor, but the easiest and best solution is to use separate containers. You can find stock containers for [mysql](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and also for [python](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/python/), which would save you a lot of trouble. To do this:

1. Take the mysql installation stuff out of the Dockerfile
2. Change `localhost` in your python code to `mysql` or whatever you want to call your MySQL container.
3. Start a MySQL container with something like `docker run -d --name mysql mysql`
4. Start your container and link to the mysql container e.g: `docker run myapp --link mysql:mysql`

Comment: I got the same error. If I separate this in two containers, what should be in the first and what should be in second container. Did I must to linked them?

Comment: Added some instructions. Yes, links make things easier.

Comment: In python code I changed host to 'mysqlserver', which is the name of MySQL container. But I got this error: Unknown MySQL server host 'mysqlserver'.

Comment: sounds like you made a typo - what's in /etc/hosts?

Comment: /etc/hosts on my host machine?

Comment: No, in the container. There should be an entry for mysqlserver if you did it correctly, and you should be able to ping the other server.

Comment: what is command to see /etc/hosts of some docker container? Did I can see that from terminal or from dockerfile?

Comment: I really can't help you any more. I think you need to get someone to sit down with you and walk through this stuff. You can just do `docker run exec CONTAINER cat /etc/hosts` though.