# Laravel 5.1 Error - PDOException:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, laravel

I need your help for hosting a project Laravel online on a simple Gandi hosting.

I work on Mac OS X with Mamp Pro and my website works like a charm on it.

When I try to put my laravel project on Gandi hosting, i'm having trouble and I do not see where is the problem.

Here's the problem I encounter  :

[image]
I do not understand , I have changed the database.php file in the app folder to match the BDD MySQL Gandi and I have verified that my .env file is correct.

Why my project tries absolutely to connect to a unix_socket MAMP then I am no longer in local ? Someone has already experienced the problem ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443504/missing-mysql-sock-yielding-operationalerror-2002-cant-connect-to-local-my?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run?rq=1

Comment: use database host 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `mysql-server` installed that handles connections for the client.

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Try other options in the answers I mentioned in comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

check MySQL whether to start, Whether the service is normal

try: service mysqld start